# How to use instance profile IAM role when ~/.aws/credentials are configured

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have IAM instance profile attached to an ec2. Also i have configured credentials in ~/.aws/credentials (access key and secret key, all have different set of permissions).
How i will use roles/permissions attached with my instance profile in ec2 while running aws cli commands.
please suggest.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-metadata.html#cli-configure-metadata-configure

Comment: @jellycsc yes i did, after doing this i was getting error An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/xx/xx is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xx:role/xx, then i add assume role permission to role and then it worked, Many Thanks